# How should I prepare my repository for future patches?

Tags: svn, workflow, patch, branching-and-merging

Let's say I keep only working tested code in **trunk**. Each iteration is done in a separate **branch**.

When the iteration is over I **merge** the changes back into **trunk**.

What should I do then?

Today I kill the dev **branch**, create a **tag** of the **trunk** at that given moment of **release**. Then my idea is to create a branch of that tag if a patch is needed while the next iteration is underway.

Is it better to keep the development branch alive to apply future patches there? I don't think I like that idea :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You **can** have **long-live branch** (never closed) (ALL-TIME-DEVEL) and periodically merge it to trunk - this pattern will work
- You **can** from other side have **short-term branches** in paradigm branch-per-task and after finishing task merge to trunk with --reintegrate (close branch practically and delete after it)

Both workflows **are not** mutually exclusive and **can co-exist**: it's *your choice*, how to work

Your current workflow (stable trunk, move *mayor releases* into separate branches (for bugfix releases)) and mark *every release* with tag is perfectly viable